# In "The Old Man and the Sea", what happened to the ridiculous fish?

Tags: ernest-hemingway, the-old-man-and-the-sea

In the pretty end of Hemingway's story 'The Old Man and The Sea', was the fish all eaten by sharks? Did Santiago have his own share?

Answer (score 5):

The sharks ate almost all of it, leaving only the skeleton, head, and tail.

Excerpt from the text (emphasis mine):

> One came, finally, against the head itself and he knew that it was over. He swung the tiller
>   across the shark’s head where the jaws were caught in the heaviness of the fish’s head which would
>   not tear. He swung it once and twice and again. He heard the tiller break and he lunged at the shark
>   with the splintered butt. He felt it go in and knowing it was sharp he drove it in again. The shark let
>   go and rolled away. That was the last shark of the pack that came. **There was nothing more for
>   them to eat**.

....

> He stopped for a moment and
>   looked back and saw in the reflection from the street light the great tail of the fish standing up well
>   behind the skiff’s stern. **He saw the white naked line of his backbone and the dark mass of the head
>   with the projecting bill and all the nakedness between**.

Arguably, the fish head contains some meat, but the point is that the main prize was lost.

Comment: Thank you! I was thrilled after completing the book with complete understanding. :)

Comment: @ClaudiaSTP: If you feel I answered your question, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.